# Where is the source of my "cannot find path" error? (Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage)

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I'm getting an error on a script I'm working on that deprovisions some Win10 bloatware apps.

Line 97 character 17 is the very first character of `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage` found below.

Relevant var:
`$Logfile = "$Env:SystemRoot\Temp\RemoveApps_$($Buildnr).log"`

`WriteHostFile` is a function that simply spits the text both to the terminal and `$Logfile`.

This is on a fully up to date Windows 10 Pro system, and the script is a powershell .ps1 script.

I've investigated `$Logfile` and it's not only being created, but the `Removing Provisioned Package: $ProPackageFullName` is being appended as intended. The log file can be modified and the `WriteHostFile` function works. (Also I know it's a bad var name. I'll make it more sensible later.)

Honestly not sure what else I can try, else I wouldn't be asking here.

```bsh
            # Removes app from provisioning
            if ($ProPackageFullName) {
                WriteHostFile "Removing Provisioned Package: $ProPackageFullName"
                start-sleep -Seconds 5 
                Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online -packagename $ProPackageFullName | Out-File -FilePath $Logfile -Append -Encoding ascii
```

The error:

```
Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage : The system cannot find the path specified.
At [redacted directory]\RemoveApps.ps1:97 char:17
+ ...             Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online -packagename $ProPa ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.RemoveAppxProvisionedPackageCommand
```

The error only occurs on packages that are actually uninstalled. This snippit is contained within a foreach loop that first checks if the package is installed.

I've now noticed a difference between the two machines I'm testing on.
On the 1st one, running PowerShell 5.1 build 18362 revision 145, the script works correctly- removing the apps as intended.
On the 2nd one, running PowerShell 5.1 build 17134 revision 228, the script produces the above problems.

Comment: Does `Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -Online` list the package you are trying to remove? If so, what happens if you grab the target package from that command and pipe it to `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online` ?

Comment: Works for me.  Have to be admin.  Is the packagename right?  `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName Microsoft.ZuneMusic_2019.19011.11311.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`

Comment: Yes, the apps that are being removed are installed. But I just discovered that the apps that aren't getting the error are all not installed, while the ones getting the error all are. I have more code before this that detects if the package is installed before attempting to uninstall it. Package names are correct, and they're trimmed before uninstallation in case if the weird stuff before and after like `19011.11311.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe` were to change. I had an earlier version of the script that worked but now I'm not sure what went wrong. I don't remember altering this code.

Comment: I uh, just realized I did edit this section before. `$PackageFullName = (Get-AppxPackage $App -AllUsers).PackageFullName` is what I had for declaring that var. I had added `-AllUsers` because it wasn't uninstalling the app for all users, and in hindsight I'm an idiot for thinking that would work in a variable that was to be used as a string, not array.

Comment: And.. the issue still occurs even after fixing that, for some reason. Still not uninstalled, still the same error, on the same line and character.

Comment: Can you post the full code?  get-appxpackage and get-appxprovisionedpackage are two different things.  If you don't @reply anyone, they won't get notified.  get-appxpackage -allusers has no effect on which users's packages get removed.  remove-appxpackage -allusers only works in windows 10 1809 and above.

Comment: @js2010 [Sure, here](https://pastebin.com/hpfuLjHs). And I'm aware get-appxpackage is different from remove, I realized after the comment that it both didn't make sense to have it there, and that it wouldn't do anything. Also, note this script was originally [based on this one here](https://ccmexec.com/2019/04/updated-removeapps-script-for-windows-10-1903/), but as you can see I've added a lot.

Comment: Also in testing, I've noticed a difference. On one laptop I'm working on, the script works fine. On the other that still has the garbage I'm trying to clean up, the script doesn't work. I tested by reinstalling Solitaire on my first laptop, and it removed fine. Second one couldn't remove it. They're both on Win10 64bit. First one is on PS 5.1 build 18362 rev 145, second is on PS 5.1 build 17134 rev 228.

Comment: appxprovisionedpackage:  what new users will get.  appxpackage:  what current users already have.

Comment: @js2010 I'm aware of that difference. If you see my code, you'll see I'm doing both. The error may only mention provisioned, but the app is also not being uninstalled on top of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have be that complicated.

```
# "remove-appxpackage -allusers" only works starting in windows 10 version 1809, 
#   otherwise works on current user
# "remove-appxpackage -user" does not work
# remove installed apps starting with "a"
get-appxpackage -allusers a* | remove-appxpackage -whatif -allusers 

# this would ONLY delete the a* apps for the current user
get-appxpackage -allusers a* | remove-appxpackage -whatif

# remove-appxprovisionedpackage has no -whatif option
# remove "to be installed apps for new users" starting with "a"
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | where displayname -like a* | 
  Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online
```

Comment: I didn't think it had to be that complicated, but I avoided touching the original removeapps code as much as possible for fear of this exact problem (not uninstalling apps), lol. What's the `a*` part for? I tried `Get-AppxPackage a*` to see what it would output and I get nothing. Tried the whole line and got the same. Am I supposed to replace it with my $App variable, or is it something special in PowerShell?

Comment: The script you're using calls it anyway.  That should list all apps that start with the letter a, if they're installed as the current user.  Maybe you need `get-appxpackage -allusers a*`, but that doesn't affect which users get it removed.

Comment: Oh, I understand what a* was now. Completely missed two of your comment lines. I had to make some adjustments as `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage` doesn't seem to accept piping in stuff, and it's still not working. Parameter `-PackageName` is somehow getting null. I've had `Write-Host $App` right before and after just that command, and Write-Host is getting the app's correct full package name. [Here's the newest version with irrelevant functions removed](https://pastebin.com/KhC07Gfk). What's also worse is now even on my laptop with the newer version of PS, it's getting the same error.

Comment: Remove-appxprovisionedpackage accepts packagename over the pipe, but only bypropertyname, for example from get-appxprovisionedpackage.

Comment: I see. I don't see how what I tested with was any different, but copy-pasting it makes it work. Thanks.